# Django Rest Framework nested serializer

Tags: python, django, d3.js, django-rest-framework

I have models like -

```
class Sectors(models.Model):
  sector_mc = models.TextField()

class Insector(models.Model):
  foundation = models.ForeignKey(Sectors)
  name = models.TextField()
  value = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I want my data to be in a format like-

```
                        "name": "cluster",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "Tester", "value": 3938},
                            {"name": "CommunityStructure", "value": 3812},
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "graph",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "value": 34},
                            {"name": "LinkDistance", "value": 5731},
                        ]
                    }
```

So "cluster" goes in "sector_mc" of "Sectors"
 and cluster has children "Tester" and "CommunityStructure"(these go in "name" and "value" of "Insector" for cluster sector_mc)

Similarly "graph" goes in "sector_mc" of Sectors and graph has children  "BetweennessCentrality" and "LinkDistance"(these go in "name" and "value" of "Insector" for graph sector_mc)

And so on.

How to save these with the same relation in the database and also, how to use DRF to structure it in this format. I tried using nested relationship of DRF with this but reached no where.

I need the data to be in this format for d3 sunburst chart. If there are any other workarounds, I'd be very open to know them as well. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **create a `SectorSerializer`** which will contain a nested serializer `InsectorSerializer`.

Since you are using different keys for output we can use `source` to get the corresponding values from the field names.

`name` key in the output corresponds to `sector_mc`, so we use `sector_mc` as its `source`.

`children` key in the output contains all the related instances for a particular `Sectors` instance. We can use [`FOO_set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) as the source for `children` field. Also, since there will be multiple related instances, we pass `many=True` parameter along with it.

```
class InsectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Insector
        fields = ('name', 'value')


class SectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='sector_mc') # get value from 'sector_mc' 
    children = InsectorSerializer(many=True, source='insector_set') # get all related instances

    class Meta:
        model = Sectors
        fields = ('name', 'children')
```

Comment: So I get the serialized Response but children doesn't have anything. Maybe if you could check the view that I have? @Rahul

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also, check in Python shell whether for a particular `Sectors` instance that you can access `.insector_set.all()` i.e. all the related `Insector` instances. Try without `many=True` argument also.

Comment: Without many=True, I get "children": {
            "name": null
        }

Comment: @ThatBird Did you check in python shell for the attribute to access all related `Insector` instances?

Comment: It gave me insector is not defined

Comment: Please check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) on how to access relationships from reverse. Then check what attribute is present on a `Sectors` instance to access the related `Insector` instances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114736/discussion-between-thatbird-and-rahul-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in my views file while saving data to models. DRF worked fine when views problem solved.

Comment: Hi, @ThatBird, I am facing the same problem - "I get the serialized Response but children doesn't have anything.". Could you please share what was wrong in your views file while saving data to models.